# Mariadb- Calculate the volume of changes per day

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database on a Linux Server. I want to calculate the amount of changes by the database per day.

```
what I need = the volume of changed data (update/delete) + new data (insert).
```

This helps me to calculate if the amount of free space is suitable for the lvm-snapshot or not.

Only the database uses our linux sever and there isn't another application.

Answer (score 2):

If its all Innodb then [innodb_pages_written](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-status-variables/#innodb_pages_written) * [innodb_page_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-status-variables/#innodb_page_size).

As changes are written to the redo log, add to this amount the lesser of [innodb_log_file_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size) and the amount already calculated. We use the minimum as the redo log is a circular buffer and won't ever use more than its maximum amount.

What this doesn't account for is the number of times the same page is changed multiple times in different flushes which will mean the snapshot requirement becomes less. But for a pessimistic estimate the above should be a good metric.

Comment: Yes. It's innodb. But there is no "innodb_pages_written" Parameter in mariadb 10.3. If the database had this parameter, how could I calculate the volume changes in the last twenty-four hours.

Comment: @TimLer innodb_pages_written is a status variable. Can be retrieved like this: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_pages_written';`

Comment: STATUS values start with a capital letter (mostly).  Divide that value by `Uptime` to get the average since MariaDB was restarted.  Then multiply by 16KB.